# Binding a List To a comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, object, user-interface, combobox

I have a List of `Person` objects (which is loaded from the database), I call it `PersonList`. `Person` class has four attributes `Person_Id(PK)`, `Name`, `Family` and `Address`.

I want to bind the context of this list to a `ComboBox`. Also I want to show both `Name` and `Family` of each person in ComboBox (not the `Person_Id` or `Address`). On the other hand I want to gain Person_Id(PK) of the selected value of ComboBox if the end user selects  anyone.

How can I manage to do this? Also I'm wondering if I delete any items of `PersonList` the ComboBox updates automatically or I Should update manually by myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your Person class a readonly property that returns the string desired

```
class Person
{
    public int Person_ID {get;set;}
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string family {get;set;}
    public int address {get;set;}
    public string name_family { get {return this.ToString();}}

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.name, this.family);
    }
}
```

now assign the property `DisplayMember` of the combobox to the read only property and the ValueMember  property  to the Person_ID of the class Person.

```
comboBox1.DataSource = PersonList;
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name_family";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
```

Now in the combobox `SelectedIndexChange` event you could retrieve the ID from the SelectedItemValue

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(comboBox1.SelectedValue != null)
    {
       int personID = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue);
       .......
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but still remains one unsolved question? If I put a button in the form which by clicking that do this work:  PersonList.RemoveAt(0); I want not to see the first item of the comboBox too without any further of programming. Is it possible?